# Aplicações GUI - Agilizando! Como?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Olá, pessoal!

Minha missão é dar agilidade e fluidez a um software... deixar ele sem aquelas travadas constantes em cada For...

Para isso eu criei um problema e gostaria de saber se alguém consegue resolver. A solução será aplicada em grande parte do meu sistema

A função abaixo é responsável por realizar diversos cálculos complexos e ao ser chamada trava o formulário por completo. O desafio é rodar isso aí em segundo plano e ainda receber a resposta: (true/false)

```
Public Function MinhaFuncao() As Boolean

    Try
        'Realiza os cálculos'

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception

        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Já tentei utilizar Threads... Ficou algo assim:

```
Dim minhaThread As Threading.Thread
minhaThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MinhaFuncao)
minhaThread.IsBackground = True
minhaThread.Start()
```

De fato funcionou! Mas não me retornou nenhuma resposta...

Bom, de toda forma, agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A utilização de threads directamente é desaconselhada.

O ideal é usar uma abstracção de alto nível, como [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx). Estas encapsulam lógica que deve ser executada assincronamente, e propagam os valores de retorno.

Além disso, também propagam excepções - se alguma excepção ocorrer na background thread, será re-lançada na thread principal com o uso de `await`, `Wait`, ou `Result`.

Nao estou familiarizado com a sintaxe de VB.NET, mas eis como o fazer em C# usando [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) (que defere o trabalho para uma thread da thread pool):

```
bool result = await Task.Run(MinhaFuncao);
```

(Nota: se isto for um projecto pessoal, aconselho a usar C# em vez de VB.NET. É muito mais fácil encontrar recursos online e materiais de ajuda para C#)

---

Após um pouco de investigação, julgo que a sintaxe em vb.net seja:

```
Await Task.Run(AddressOf MinhaFuncao);
```

Comment: Entendi dcastro!

Essa é uma ótimo solução cara. Funcionou aqui!! Heheheh

Sobre migrar para C#... eu até já considerei, mas nasci no VB, não dá para abandonar agora kkkkk E no fundo os dois compartilham das mesmas ferramentas ^^

Comment: Solução: Dim resposta As Boolean = Await Task.Run(Of Boolean)(Function() (MinhaFuncao))